# Нужна ли запятая перед «И» в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

«Однако в мэрии решили убрать здание(,) и обложили его динамитом».

Нужна ли запятая и почему?

Answer (score 4):

***Однако в мэрии решили убрать здание и обложили его динамитом.***

Конечно, запятая в вашем предложении не нужна, потому что союз *и* соединяет однородные сказуемые.

Это односоставное неопределённо-личное предложение.

https://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/222

> Неопределенно-личные предложение
>  
> Неопределенно-личные предложения — это односоставные предложения с главным членом сказуемым, передающие действия неопределенного субъекта. 
>  
> В неопределённо-личных предложениях главный член выражается глаголом в форме 3 лица множественного числа (настоящего и будущего времени в изъявительном наклонении и в повелительном наклонении), формой множественного числа прошедшего времени изъявительного наклонения и аналогичной формой условного наклонения глагола. 
>  
> Производитель действия в этих предложениях неизвестен или неважен.
> Например: В доме стучали печными дверцами (А. Толстой); На улицах где-то далеко стреляют (Булгаков); Дали бы человеку отдохнуть перед дорогой (Шолохов).

Производитель действия нам неизвестен и неважен (мы просто знаем, что это кто-то из мэрии).

В этом предложении два однородных сказуемых: первое сказуемое — составное глагольное (вспомогательный глагол которого как раз 3-го лица множественного числа), а второе — простое глагольное (глагол тоже 3-го лица множественного числа).

Пусть вас не пугает, что сказуемые разных видов — такое встречается часто. Главное, что это простое предложение (производитель действия один) с двумя однородными членами, соединенными одиночным союзом *и*, и потому запятую мы **не ставим!**

Но! Советую обратить внимание на сам смысл предложения: не кажется ли вам, что он искажен? Действительно, депутаты из мэрии могут вынести решение о сносе здания, но они ли, в своих пиджачках, пойдут обкладывать его динамитом? Судя по построению вашего предложения, это сделали именно депутаты — вынесли решение и пошли обкладывать. Поэтому корректнее было бы построить предложение так:

***Однако в мэрии решили убрать здание, для чего оно было обложено динамитом.***

Или так:

***Однако в мэрии решили убрать здание, для чего его обложили динамитом.***

Comment: Игорь, а вам предложение не кажется странным? Стилистически, например?

Comment: Кажется, конечно, но я ответил автору именно по его варианту предложения, хоть и не совсем удачному

Comment: Против самого ответа я не возражаю, но про стилистику можно бы что-нибудь добавить. Еще к вам такая просьба: ссылаться желательно  в первую очередь на Розенталя, так как это официальный источник. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

Comment: Насчёт предложения, тут, конечно, нужен контекст. Само по себе оно выглядит ужасно нелогичным, такого тут не может быть. Сдается мне, там весь текст нужно переделывать. А что бы вы с этим предложением сделали, не имея контекста?

Comment: К примеру, такой вариант: "Однако в мэрии решили убрать здание, для чего его  обложили  динамитом". Здесь я как бы специально разделяю производителей действия. В мэрии принимают решения, а исполняет его кто-то еще.

Comment: Конечно, я тоже переделал подобным образом, но опубликовать побоялся — не уверен в себе)

Comment: А вы повторяйте каждый день: я успешный, самодостаточный и уверенный в себе. И чтобы повысить вашу уверенность, ставлю вам плюсик за ответ

Comment: Спасибо! Дополнил ответ.